# How to access form action value in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have a webpage in `asp.net` with form having id `"form1"` like this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

It converts to following when page rendered when I browse like:

```
localhos/default1.aspx/john
```

The rendered html is following:

```
<form method="post" action="john" id="form1">
```

How can I access action value `"john"` in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Since its converted to Url (localhos/default1.aspx/john), then in C#

```
Protected void Page_Load()

{
string CurrentUrl=HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string ActionName = CurrentUrl.Split('/')[CurrentUrl.count.Split('/').Count-1];


}
```

//or the other option is to convert your form to run at the server, since C# can only access server side controls:

```
<form="form1" runat="server" action="john"/>
```

//and then in your C# code behind

```
protected void Page_Load()
{

string FormAction=form1.Action;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get action using `form1.Action`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.action(v=vs.110).aspx

which is empty by default and replaced by actual rawurl.

So, if form1.Action is empty, just get Request.RawUrl or Request.Url and get the last segment

Example:

```
if (form1.Action == String.Empty)
    Response.Write("action=" 
         + Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length-1]);
```

Comment: How can u access a form in C# without specifiying Runat=Server !!!!  the form is on client side in the above code !!!

Comment: The form is set as *runat="server"*. See the original question.